# Sprint em metodologia Scrum não pode ter o escopo negociado?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos, metodologia, metodologia-ágil, scrum

A respeito da **metodologia Scrum**, gostaria de saber.

> É correto afirmar se durante a **Sprint**:
>
> > O escopo **pode ser** clarificado e renegociado entre o Product Owner e a Equipe de Desenvolvimento.

Ao ler sobre o assunto, interpretei não ser possível renegociar ou mudar as decisões definidas após a **Sprint Planning Meeting**, quando ocorre a reunião entre o **product Owner** e a **Scrum Team**, O site [sobre Metodologia Scrum](http://www.desenvolvimentoagil.com.br/scrum/product_owner) explicita bem o assunto.

O problema é que a afirmação veio de uma resposta correta [dessa questão](https://www.aprovaconcursos.com.br/questoes-de-concurso/questao/139586), que eu errei ao tentar responder.

Comment: Cara na prática da sim, só em casos isolados e se o PO for maleável, caso contrário ele irá exigir que siga para próxima sprint e em outro momento retornar no projeto que foi impactado

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/207520)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece mais uma questão de interpretação de texto. O fato é que por eliminação as outras 4 respostas são muito piores, elas falam de coisas que afetam o resultado.

A resposta correta fala em renegociação, só não fala que normalmente ela parte da equipe de desenvolvimento quando entende que o escopo não está adequado e vai descobrindo ao longo do *sprint*. O texto do site fala que o o dono do projeto não deve mudar o escopo por sua iniciativa trocando o que estava previsto no *sprint*, ou seja, não pode ele não pode colocar novos requisitos que afetem o desenvolvimento daquele *sprint* sob pena de não conseguir cumpri-lo.

Na prática isto afeta negativamente o desenvolvimento, não vou entrar em detalhes para evitar polêmica, mas imagina uma mudança de planos não poder interferir no desenvolvimento e ter que continuar fazendo algo que depois terá que ser refeito para atender a burocracia. E tem gente que diz que a metodologia existe para desburocratizar.

A frase da opção da pergunta provavelmente foi tirada da página 9 de um [guia de Scrum](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2017/2017-Scrum-Guide-US.pdf).

Considero que o site brasileiro é, no mínimo, confuso no que fala.

Comment: Imaginei que fosse interpretação de texto, sempre caiu em alguma armadilha, é sempre bom tentar entrar em consenso com mais alguém, agradeço por responder =)